# Variants of the Basel problems

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The Basel problem asserts $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, the well-known proof uses the Fourier series of $f(x)=x^2$.

Question: has somebody computed sums of the form $$\sum\frac{1}{(n+\frac{1}{2})^2}$$
or
$$\sum\frac{1}{n^2+1}?$$
The approach via Fourier series seems not to generalize.

Comment: The first follows easily from $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$ (you get it from the sum for odd $n$, which you get by subtracting off the sum for even $n$).

Comment: Right, thank you. Actually, I had thought of the first one as an instance of the general $\sum\frac{1}{(n+a)^2}$ (with $a$ not a natural number) and in this generality the argument still does not seem to generalize.

Comment: You can see [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.00957.pdf) for some alternating variants of the second sum, i.e., of the form $\sum_{n \geq 1} (-1)^n / (n^2+1)^s$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes actually we know the exact value of $$S = \sum_{m=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{am^2+b},$$ with $a,b >0$. This is computed using the classical residue method with $\pi \operatorname{cotg}(\pi z).$ You will eventually get $$S = \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\pi \coth(\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}\pi)}{\sqrt{ab}}-\frac{1}{b}\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

For the question in your comments$$\sum_{n=p}^q\frac{1}{(n+a)^2}=\psi ^{(1)}(a+p)-\psi ^{(1)}(a+q+1)$$ where appears the [polygamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function) $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+a)^2}=\psi ^{(1)}(a)$$ $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+a)^2}=\psi ^{(1)}(a+1)$$